# MySQL Stored Procedure: What I am doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

What is wrong in the following code (please forgive me for very basic question)

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getCleanData` ()
BEGIN
    replace into CLEAN_TBL SELECT mycolumn  FROM DIRTY_TBL;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the [DELIMITER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html) to something else than the default `;`.

A DELIMITER tells whe the command ends. By default the delimiter is `;`. As procedure itself uses `;` in it's syntax (end of statement), you need to change the DELIMITER to something else to that the full procedure code will be executed.

Comment: Still not sure why it is expected to change the DELIMITER ....when the user is using CREATE PROCEDURE .... is it not obvious what he/she is trying to...

Answer (score 0):

Step 01: change server delimiter -->
`DELIMITER //`

Step 02: create your procedure with new delimiter you used in step 01

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getCleanData` ()
BEGIN
 replace into CLEAN_TBL SELECT mycolumn  FROM DIRTY_TBL;
END
//
```

**DON'T TRY TO REVERT THE DELIMITER**

Right way to do from experts are welcome, because I am not sure what is the right way.....but I feel not having the default delimiter for CREATE PROCEDURE is wrong.